# Coordinate system for South Africa

Tags: coordinate-system, units, smallworld-gis, south-africa

What coordinate System can I apply to South Africa in GE Smallworld 5.1?The CS  units should be in meters.
1.I understand that the datum used is 'hartebeesthoek_1994' , Is it necessary to create 'WGzones' from WG17 to WG31 as mentioned online?Can I create a single coordinate system for the entire country?
2.As Smallworld Doesn't support TM south based projection, I was wondering if I can apply Traverse mercator projection? If yes, what should be the parameters?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE venugopal. Please edit your question to include a single answerable question following the site guidelines: http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: The EPSG dataset contains information about most, if not all, commonly used coordinate reference systems. Hartebeesthoek 1994 seems to be EPSG:4148, see http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4184/. But the 'WGzones' are also included in the EPSG dataset, e.g., EPSG:2072.

Comment: Do you have the possibility to define a custom projected coordinate reference system? If so, duplicate the zone definition but make the scale factor -1.0.